# Bash string manipulation, extracting/removing parts

Tags: bash

I'm modifying an old bash file and am having some trouble manipulating strings. The problem is that the strings can be anything random to the left of `_<date>.<num>`. For example, from `ThisIsAString-Sub_tag_150827.1`, I need to extract  `_150827.1`. In bash, this seems very difficult to do. In any other language, I would split on `_`, and just grab the last element of the list. How do I do this in bash? I've tried a few different ways (including with awk), but cannot seem to get it right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With bash's Parameter Expansion:

```
a="ThisIsAString-Sub_tag_150827.1"
echo "${a##*_}"
```

Output:

```
150827.1
```

Comment: hmm... I actually tried something really similar... ${string#_*}

Comment: @user797963 with `##` instead of `#`, Bash will remove the longest matching string, not the shortest; using `#` would leave you with the "tag_" prefix. See [the man page here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

Comment: The order of `_` and `*` is important.

Comment: Thanks guys, this was hugely helpful.